# Jbehave Maven Exception

Tags: maven, build, hudson, testcase, jbehave

I've integrated Jbehave test in Hudson as A Maven goal but whenever I run Test via Hudson-web-interface, I get following error

```
 BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Total time: 33.609s
 [INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 03 15:08:52  2012
 [INFO] Final Memory: 26M/81M
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
 [INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - [1]    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:4.0-beta-2:run-stories-as-paths (run-stories-as-paths) on project ABCServices: Failed to run stories as paths
 [DEBUG] Closing connection to remote
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:4.0-beta-2:run-stories-as-paths (run-stories-as-paths) on project ABCServices:
 Failed to run stories as paths: Story path '.svn/all-wcprops' not found by class loader EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[/Users/abc/.hudson/jobs/TestHudson/workspace/target/test-classes/, /Users/abc/.hudson/jobs/TestHudson/workspace/target/classes/, SSIOServicesClient-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, poi-3.8.jar, cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.5.2.jar, xml-resolver-1.2.jar, asm-3.3.jar, cxf-api-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-core-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.5.2.jar, cxf-tools-common-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-transports-http-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-transports-common-2.5.2.jar, cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.5.0.jar, cxf-common-utilities-2.5.0.jar, jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, jettison-1.3.jar, jaxb-api-2.1.jar, stax-api-1.0-2.jar, activation-1.1.jar, cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.5.0.jar, xmlschema-core-2.0.1.jar, woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar, stax2-api-3.1.1.jar, geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar, geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar, neethi-3.0.1.jar, wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar, geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar, geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar, aopalliance-1.0.jar, spring-asm-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, jetty-continuation-7.5.3.v20111011.jar, jetty-http-7.5.3.v20111011.jar, jetty-io-7.5.3.v20111011.jar, jetty-util-7.5.3.v20111011.jar, jetty-security-7.5.3.v20111011.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar, geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar, log4j-1.2.16.jar, gson-1.7.1.jar, jaxb-impl-2.0.3.jar, jsr173_api-1.0.jar, testng-6.5.1.jar, junit-4.10.jar, hamcrest-core-1.1.jar, bsh-2.0b4.jar, jcommander-1.12.jar, snakeyaml-1.6.jar, spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, commons-lang-2.5.jar, spring-test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, commons-httpclient-3.1.jar, commons-codec-1.2.jar, SharedshelfSchema-0.7.jar, xom-1.2.5.jar, xml-apis-1.3.03.jar, xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar, xalan-2.7.0.jar, json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar, commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, ezmorph-1.0.6.jar, VWWebServicesClient-1.0.jar, httpclient-4.2.1.jar, httpcore-4.2.1.jar, httpmime-4.0.1.jar, apache-mime4j-0.6.jar, json-20090211.jar, hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar, hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar, antlr-2.7.6.jar, dom4j-1.6.1.jar, jta-1.1.jar, hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar, cglib-2.2.jar, javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, morphia-0.99.1-SNAPSHOT.jar, mongo-java-driver-2.10.0.jar, cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar, jbehave-maven-plugin-4.0-beta-3.jar, jbehave-core-4.0-beta-3.jar, junit-dep-4.8.2.jar, hamcrest-library-1.1.jar, hamcrest-integration-1.1.jar, commons-io-1.4.jar, plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar, freemarker-2.3.16.jar, paranamer-2.4.jar, xstream-1.3.1.jar, xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, maven-plugin-api-2.0.11.jar, maven-artifact-2.0.11.jar, maven-project-2.0.11.jar, maven-settings-2.0.11.jar, maven-profile-2.0.11.jar, maven-model-2.0.11.jar, maven-artifact-manager-2.0.11.jar, maven-repository-metadata-2.0.11.jar, wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar, maven-plugin-registry-2.0.11.jar, plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar, plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar, classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar, plexus-archiver-1.2.jar, plexus-io-1.0.1.jar, proxytoys-1.0.jar, tuprolog-extensions-2.1.1.jar, tuprolog-2.1.1.jar, xunit-1.9.jar, guice-2.0.1.jar, dtkit-metrics-model-0.8.jar, dtkit-metrics-util-0.8.jar, saxon-9.1.0.8.jar, saxon-9.1.0.8-s9api.jar, saxon-9.1.0.8-dom.jar, dtkit-metrics-hudson-api-0.8.jar, dtkit-junit-model-0.8.jar, dtkit-default-junit-hudson-0.9.jar, dtkit-default-junit-0.9.jar],parent=ClassRealm[plugin>org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:4.0-beta-2, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5ab8df17]] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]
```

Please tell me what should I do to resolve this issue.

PS: I am not using any Source Code Management.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.It happened because of the difference between Maven versions I integrated in Hudson and the version with which my application's pom working.

application was working with Maven2 and Hudson was working with Maven3, I configured hudson with Maven2 and it workd fine.